# how to run spark batch jobs in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, spark-submit

I'm trying to run batch jobs in VS code, but I keep getting an error telling me to sign in first and I'm not sure why.
My settings.json is set with my file:

```
{
    "hdinsightJobSubmission.ClusterConf": [
        {
            "name": "Hue: http://xumclu123.td.knv:8998 (franklinm23)",
            "filePath": "c:\\Users\\franklinm23\\Spark\\HelloWorld.py"
        }
    ],
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\franklinm23\\.msvscode.hdinsight\\hdinsightJupyter\\Scripts\\python.exe"
}
```

When I right-click on my helloworld.py I get this as the output:

```
[2021-1-15:13:54:21] [Info] Set Hive: http://xumclu123.td.knv:8998 as the default job submission cluster!
```

Then when I right-click Spark: PySpark Batch I get:

```
[2021-1-15:13:56:13] [Info] start submitting spark application to cluster Hive: http://xumclu123.td.knv:8998 (franklinm23)
[2021-1-15:13:56:13] [Error] Error: please sign in at first!
```

I've tried all my clusters and they're all running. What am I missing in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User was not properly signed in.